How can we cast a `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)` to `int`?
I think this is a simple task, but I could not find a solution on the web to this. I have a external C++ library, which I'm using in my Python code, returning a ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) to me. I want to pass an array of these pointers to a jax.vmap function. The problem is that jax does not accept the ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) type. So, can I somehow cast this pointer to an ordinary int. Technically, this is clearly possible. But how do I do this in Python?
Here is an example:
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path)
lib.foo.argtypes = None
lib.foo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)

bar = jax.vmap(lambda : dummy lib.foo())(jax.numpy.empty(16))

x = jax.numpy.empty(16, 256, 256, 1)
y = jax.vmap(lib.bar, in_axes = (0, 1))(x, bar)

So, I want to invoke lib.foo 16-times so that I have an array bar containing all the pointers. Then I want to invoke another library function lib.bar which expects bar together with another (batched) parameter x.
The problem is that jax claims that ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) is not a valid jax type. This is why I think the solution is to cast the pointers to ints and store those ints in bar instead.

Can you add a simple example describing how the outcome should be?

Lame: lib.foo.restype = ctypes.c_size_t?

@CristiFati jax doesn't support any ctypes type. So, unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

But combined with bar = jax.vmap(lambda dummy: lib.foo().value)(jax.numpy.empty(16)) (something seems wrong in the way you wrote the lambda)?

Or lib.foo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) (as it was) and bar = jax.vmap(lambda dummy: ctypes.cast(lib.foo(), ctypes.c_void_p).value)(jax.numpy.empty(16))

I found the other question (I should have figured out it has already been answered).

@CristiFati Your second idea actually should be the solution. However, when I execute this I get the error that the value returned is too large to fit into a int32. This is clearly correct (on a 64-bit system), but I don't get why the code tries to convert to int32 at all.

Listing:

[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) - a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions)

[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python


Here's a piece of code exemplifying how to handle pointers and their addresses. The trick is to use ctypes.addressof (documented in the 2nd URL).
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys


CType = cts.c_float
CTypePtr = cts.POINTER(CType)


def ctype_pointer(seq):  # Helper
    CTypeArr = (CType * len(seq))
    ctype_arr = CTypeArr(*seq)
    return cts.cast(ctype_arr, CTypePtr)


def pointer_elements(addr, count):  # Helper
    return tuple(CType.from_address(addr + i * cts.sizeof(CType)).value for i in range(count))


def main(*argv):
    seq = (2.718182, -3.141593, 1.618034, -0.618034, 0)
    ptr = ctype_pointer(seq)
    print(f"Pointer: {ptr}")
    print(f"\nPointer elements: {tuple(ptr[i] for i in range(len(seq)))}")  # Check if pointer has correct data
    ptr_addr = cts.addressof(ptr.contents)  # @TODO - cfati: Straightforward
    print(f"\nAddress: {ptr_addr} (0x{ptr_addr:016X})\nElements from address: {pointer_elements(ptr_addr, len(seq))}")
    ptr_addr0 = cts.cast(ptr, cts.c_void_p).value  # @TODO - cfati: Alternative
    print(f"\nAddresses match: {ptr_addr == ptr_addr0}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Notes:

Although it adds a bit of complexity, I introduced the CType "layer" to show that it should work with any type, not just float (as long as the values in the sequence are of that type)

The only truly relevant lines are those marked with @TODO


Output:

(py_pc064_03.08_test0_lancer) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q078366208]> python ./code00.py 
Python 3.8.19 (default, Apr  6 2024, 17:58:10) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux

Pointer: <__main__.LP_c_float object at 0x7203e97e7d40>

Pointer elements: (2.71818208694458, -3.1415929794311523, 1.6180340051651, -0.6180340051651001, 0.0)

Address: 125361127594576 (0x00007203E97A9A50)
Elements from address: (2.71818208694458, -3.1415929794311523, 1.6180340051651, -0.6180340051651001, 0.0)

Addresses match: True

Done.



Both approaches yield the error that the value returned is too large to fit into an int32. This is clearly true (on a 64-bit system), but why does the system try to convert to int32 at all?

(I'm working with Python 3.11 64-bit)

It seems to work when I add an explicit cast to int64 ... Seems like jax is implicitly assuming a return type of int32 without the cast.

Strangely enough, I need to use numpy.int64; jax.numpy.int64 also yields the previous error.

That;s perfectly normal (the error). But JAX defaulting to 032 bit on 064 bit Python seems strange to me (I never used it so I can't have an opinion). Are you sure this is the correct way to call it?

I just noticed that the values in the generated array are all equal. It seems like foo is only called once and then replicated 16-times. Any idea how to solve this?

Not sure what the function returns / should return. But you can play with JAX alone (without CTypes) by mocking that function.
